# Crear un .exe con PyInstaller de un solo ejecutable (--onefile) con el archivo .spec modificado

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller, exe

Estoy intentando crear un ejecutable con PyInstaller a partir de un código en Python + GUI Tkinter. En el tkinter he incluido un directorio resources donde hay un icon.png y un icon.ico, juntamente con otro directorio yamlConf con dos archivos yaml dentro de este.

Para incluir dichos directorios en el ejecutable he modificado el archivo .spec de la siguiente manera:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-
    block_cipher = None
    a = Analysis(['index.py'],
                 pathex=['C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Desktop\\carpeta'],
                 binaries=[],
                 datas=[('./resources/icon.png', 'resources'),
                        ('./resources/icon.ico', 'resources'),
                        ('./confYaml/conf.yaml', 'confYaml'),
                        ('./confYaml/confData.yaml', 'confYaml')
                        ],
                 hiddenimports=['babel.numbers'],
                 hookspath=[],
                 runtime_hooks=[],
                 excludes=[],
                 win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
                 win_private_assemblies=False,
                 cipher=block_cipher,
                 noarchive=False)
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
                 cipher=block_cipher)
    exe = EXE(pyz,
              a.scripts,
              [],
              exclude_binaries=True,
              name='index',
              debug=False,
              bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
              strip=False,
              upx=True,
              console=True )
    coll = COLLECT(exe,
                   a.binaries,
                   a.zipfiles,
                   a.datas,
                   strip=False,
                   upx=True,
                   upx_exclude=[],
                   name='index')
```

Si ejecuto el comando:

> pyinstaller --onefile --windowed index.spec

Me crea los directorios /build & /dist correctamente pero dentro de /dist me encuentro la carpeta con todos los archivos creados por PyInstaller, no solo un ejecutable que es lo que yo quiero.

Necesito modificar el .spec ya que sino la 'aplicación' no se ejecuta correctamente.

¿Es correcta la config. del archivo spec que he adjuntado? ¿Se puede solucionar de algún modo?

> VERSIÓN PYTHON: Python 3.9.5

> VERSIÓN PYINSTALLER: 4.3

> SO: WINDOWS 10

Gracias